# MPU6050 Measure distance traveled or position

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics, mpu6050

How can I use MPU-6050 with an arduino to measure the distance the robot traveled from it's starting point or just it's current position on the map?

The Robot should be moving in a map same as a 2D array and I need to detect it's position while it is moving and send the data to a station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't - not with any degree of accuracy anyway.

You could attempt "dead reckoning" whereby you estimate the current speed by the acceleration and deceleration over time, and from that get a rough idea about the distance travelled in any one direction, but the accuracy will be so poor and the drift so huge that it would be next to pointless.

Instead you really want to monitor the wheels. Count how many revolutions (or half revolutions, quarter revolutions, whatever accuracy you need) and combine that with the circumference of the wheels to calculate how far you have travelled.